# "Usual" functions vs function variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between

```
function MyFunc() {
    // code...
}
```

and

```
var MyFunc = function() {
    // code...
};
```

in JavaScript?

Comment: Wow, i have been working javascript for YEARs and I didn't know this... CRAZY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This article might answer your question : [JavaScript function declaration ambiguity](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-function-declaration-ambiguity/).

Only the first one is an actual function declaration, whereas the shorthand method is just a regular variable declaration with an anonymous function assigned to it as its value.

*(look at the comments, too, which might get some useful informations too)*

Comment: Be careful with the comments; Several of them are incorrect.

Comment: A link may explain everything but it's always a bit nicer to have a small synopsis here too.

Answer (score 9):

I know that a difference between them is that named functions work everywhere regardless you declare them, functions in variables don't.

```
a();//works   
function a(){..}
```

works

```
a();//error
var a=function(){..}
```

doesn't work but if you call it after the declaration it works

```
var a=function(){..}
a();//works
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference superficially, so you can use both formats in your code.

To js interpreter it is different though.

First one is a named funciton.

Second one is an anonymous function that gets assigned to a variable.

Also, while debugging, you won't get a name of for the second function in stack trace.